Godot 4.3 шакаливание TextureRect
При приближении в редакторе оно фиксится в некоторых диапозонах, но во время игры выглядит сильно шакальным.
Пробовал ставить разные фильтры - linear, nearest. Ничего не поменялось. В настройках годота потыкал, но ничего не помогло. Подскажите, что можно сделать?


Про что-нибудь связанное с mipmaps не забыли?

При импорте нашел generate mipmaps или типо того, также в текстура поставил linear mipmap. Стало лучше, но теперь мыльно чересчур. Может есть еще какое-то решение?
